# Application reloads .net libraries. Why and how to avoid it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll

I had written wpf application, it works well, but sometimes it reload .net system libraries, and duration of reloading libraries could take down to ~1.2 seconds...

I know it because I was watching processes on my computer with another program.
There are some examples.

> **1.2050377** sec -
> C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\d17606e813f01376bd0def23726ecc62\WindowsBase.ni.dll
>
> 0.036563 sec -
> C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\246f1a5abb686b9dcdf22d3505b08cea\mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> 0.006741 sec -
> C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\246f1a5abb686b9dcdf22d3505b08cea\mscorlib.ni.dll

Sometimes it reload PresentationCore.dll, sometimes clr.dll or mscorlib.dll..

Why does this happened? I thought these libs must already be in memory.
How can I avoid these reloads?

I have found nothing about this theme..

Will NGen help me?

Thank you

---

**UPDATE:**

These reloads take place more often on  Windows 7 x86, but not on Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: maybe it is because you are [profiling the application.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/12/10/creating-ngen-pdbs-for-profiling-reports.aspx)

Comment: I don't use ngen now.. but yes, I have .pdb files in my release folder. You think it may cause these reloads?

Comment: I don't know. I thought the article is related to your question at first glance, but not sure when read it again.